# Save ViewPager fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, restore, savestate

- I have an MainActivity that contains a ViewPager backed by FragmentStatePageAdapter with 2 fragments, Fragment1 and Fragment2.
- Fragment1 contains a recyclerview with
  Cardviews.
- OnItemClick on recyclerview goes to a new
  DetailsActivity.

When I press back button on DetailsActivity, MainActivity is recreating everything(ViewPager) and new instances of Fragment 1 and Fragment 2 are created. Is this the right approach or is there a way to save the viewpager and fragment instances?

Comment: It should not recreate everything by default. When you open a new activity the current one goes to onPause() and then when you get back from details activity the onResume() gets called. It's still the same instance of activity. If the UI gets recreated then you are probably doing this in onResume of the MainActivity or inside your fragments (1, 2)

Comment: Can you post your MainActivity code?

Comment: You can: 1. add a check inside `onCreateView` of the fragments that checks if `savedInstanceState` is null or not. If not - prevent whatever you want. 2. make your fragments `static` 3. use singletones

Answer (score 0):

Check fragments how added this is in the form new instance() or not.if it is not try